# Unable to pull Category Description, Mage 1.9 with multiple stores,

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-attribute

so I am not sure how to debug this. 
I can pull all information from a category but I cannot get the 'description' attribute to pull through. It just appears blank.

This doesn't work:

```
<?php 
    ...
    $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    ...
?>

<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or this:

```
echo $_category->getData('description');
```

However getName, url, getting the image, or even the custom thumbnail works but just not text fields, all other attributes I can call. I am not sure if there is a setting I am missing or something else is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have mutiple store view/

Comment: Nope each Website has 1 view.

Answer (score 2):

I actually debugged it myself, as I was sure it was supposed to work.

BUT it didn't. And I traced it was because the `description` field was EMPTY. I filled the `description` field with some random text and it worked.

Modify this:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php 
    // You can put this line above, after the $_category variable for cleaner code.
    $_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription(); 
    echo ($_description) ? $_description ? "No description..."; // Or simply ''
</div>
```

Comment: This would only work if my description was actually blank. It isn't, it has text in it and still shows as blank.

Comment: That didn't go as expected... Maybe the description attribute was removed or something.. Why don't you try to debug it? 

Go to `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract` class, `_loadModelAttributes()` method. Breakpoint at line `$select = $this->_prepareLoadSelect($selects);` and get the query of that select. Copy that and manually edit the query and join it in `eav_attribute` table so you can see if the `description` attribute is in it.

Comment: The attribute exists and doesnt get missed out I can see it's existance and what I have entered into it. I'm thinking it must be a setting somewhere that is not allowing the attribute to pull to the frontend.

Comment: Of course it exists, what you need to check if the attribute `description` is pulled from database.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me :

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription();
```

or you can load the `category` collection like this :

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$description = $cat->getDescription();
```

Comment: Niether of those work for me, it should work, as getName still functions with them.

Comment: Where are you writing this piece of code?

Comment: Within the Category View. The default code doesn't even work. But it isn't erroring out, just simply believes all descriptions are null or "".